# Phonegap Page Flickering in change page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, web, phonegap-build

I am using `location.hash="Page1";` in jqueryMobile 1.4.2 to change the page but this causes the page to flicker.

```
$("#id").click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    location.hash = "Page1";
});
```

Comment: i got the solution add this line to to html file which ll cut the zoomin zoom out of page ----<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

Answer (score 0):

This resolved a similar issue I was experiencing when a text field is given focus, the screen flickers momentarily. To resolve transition problems I used the below:

This is a problem with older android device's and android versions that do not have hardware acceleration enabled thus the device is not properly double-buffered and you see the redrawing animation in all its ugly glory.

I Forced Hardware Acceleration in the application configuration. This enables double-buffering through the GPU and resolves the flickering problem. This should also resolve a few other rendering issues that may be experienced.

```
<preference name="android-hardwareAccelerated" value=" true" />
```

I set the viewport to allow a fixed header without any js library.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Last but not least you can I ussed the following CSS style in my app

```
*{
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px);
}
```